# Airflow - pass parameters between dynamic tasks

Tags: airflow

I am trying to get my head around dynamic task mapping. I need to create pretty simple workflow but I am unable to figure out how to pass arguments between different tasks.

What I have:

```py
def get_files():
    return [['23', 'abcd'], ['49', 'xyz']]

def create_instance(index, some_param, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
    return '<instance-id>'

def terminate_instance(instance_id):
    # terminate instance using instance_id
    pass

...

with dag:
    run_get_files = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'get-files',
        python_callable = get_files,
    )

    run_create_ec2_instance = PythonOperator.partial(
            task_id = 'create-instance',
            python_callable = create_instance,
        ).expand(
            op_args = run_get_files.output
    )

    start_instance = EC2StartInstanceOperator.partial(
        task_id = 'start-instance',
        region_name = 'eu-central-1',
    ).expand(
        instance_id = run_create_ec2_instance.output
    )

    run_terminate_instance = PythonOperator.partial(
            task_id = 'terminate-instance',
            python_callable = terminate_instance,
        ).expand(
            op_args = run_create_ec2_instance.output # error
    )
```

This works fine UNTIL the run_terminate_instance - somehow Airflow is not able to get the arguments correctly - it takes arguments from all instances at once (as one list). How to do this correctly, please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the set of tasks that you want to do for each key. Then expand on that TaskGroup. This was added in Airflow 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your args with `XComArg` should to the trick :

```py
from airflow import XComArg

run_create_ec2_instance = PythonOperator.partial(
    task_id = 'create-instance',
    python_callable = create_instance,
    ).expand(
            op_args = run_get_files.output
)
run_terminate_instance = PythonOperator.partial(
            task_id = 'terminate-instance',
            python_callable = terminate_instance,
        ).expand(
            op_args = XComArg(run_create_ec2_instance)
    )
```

Note : replacing the `PythonOperator` by function with `task` decorator would be easier (and recommended) as you can format the output yourself.